# Align submenu from right in ul li

Tags: css

I am working on a wordpress menu which by default in the ul li format so I have made it to look like good looking hovering menu. But problem is that all sub-menu are appearing from left, I want them to align from right instead of left. Please take a look a my code.

```css
body {
  background: #1fc59f;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu-header {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
}

.menu > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
}

.sub-menu > li > a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  color: #333;
}

.menu > li:hover > a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #96DB87;
}

.menu > li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu > li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #9DDA3E;
}
```

```html
    <div class="menu-header-container">
  <ul id="menu-header" class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#" aria-current="page">Nanomaterial Synthesis</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Metal Nanoparticles</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Non-Metal Nanoparticles</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Nanocomposite</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Carbon Nanomaterials</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#">Calculator</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Download Papers/Book Free</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to add `.sub-menu > li > a { text-align: right; }` to your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `right` property of the absolute positioned submenu. To make this work, also set the parent element to `position: relative;`.

```css
body {
  background: #1fc59f;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu-header {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
}

.menu-item {
  position: relative;
}

.menu > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

.sub-menu > li > a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  color: #333;
}

.menu > li:hover > a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #96DB87;
}

.menu > li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu > li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #9DDA3E;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-header-container">
  <ul id="menu-header" class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#" aria-current="page">Nanomaterial Synthesis</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Metal Nanoparticles</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Non-Metal Nanoparticles</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Nanocomposite</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Carbon Nanomaterials</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#">Calculator</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Download Papers/Book Free</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just to add three missing styles:

- `.menu > li { position: relative }`
- `.sub-menu { right: 0 }`
- `.sub-menu > li > a { text-align: right }`

```css
body { background: linear-gradient(90deg,#1fc59f,#9DDA3E) }
ul { list-style-type: none; padding: 0 }
a { text-decoration: none; color: #000 }
/* Menu */
#menu-header { display: flex; margin: 0; float: right }
.menu > li { position: relative }
.menu > li > a { padding: 20px; display: flex }
.sub-menu { display: none; position: absolute; right: 0; width: 150px; box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) }
.sub-menu > li > a { padding: 10px 20px; background: #fff; display: block; color: #333; text-align: right }
.menu > li:hover > a { color: #fff; background: #96DB87 }
.menu > li:hover .sub-menu { display: block }
.sub-menu > li a:hover { color: #fff; background: linear-gradient(90deg,#1fc59f,#9DDA3E) }
```

```html
<div class="menu-header-container"><ul id="menu-header" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-has-children menu-item-12"><a href="https://dheekuntal.online/" aria-current="page">Nanomaterial Synthesis</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-16"><a href="#">Metal Nanoparticles</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17"><a href="#">Non-Metal Nanoparticles</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-522" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-522"><a href="#">Nanocomposite</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-523" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-523"><a href="#">Carbon Nanomaterials</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-190" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-190"><a href="#">Calculator</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-518" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-518"><a href="#">Download Papers/Book Free</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-519" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-519"><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
body{background:linear-gradient(90deg,#1fc59f,#9DDA3E)}
ul{list-style-type:none;padding:0}
a{text-decoration:none;color:#000}
/* Menu */
#menu-header{display:flex;margin:0;float:right}
.menu > li > a{padding:20px;display:flex}
.sub-menu{display:none;position:absolute;width:150px;box-shadow:0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); text-align: right;}
.sub-menu > li > a{padding:10px 20px;background:#fff;display:block;color:#333}
.menu > li:hover > a{color:#fff;background:#96DB87}
.menu > li:hover .sub-menu{display:block}
.sub-menu > li a:hover{color:#fff;background:linear-gradient(90deg,#1fc59f,#9DDA3E)}
```

```html
<div class="menu-header-container"><ul id="menu-header" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-has-children menu-item-12"><a href="https://dheekuntal.online/" aria-current="page">Nanomaterial Synthesis</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-16"><a href="#">Metal Nanoparticles</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17"><a href="#">Non-Metal Nanoparticles</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-522" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-522"><a href="#">Nanocomposite</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-523" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-523"><a href="#">Carbon Nanomaterials</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-190" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-190"><a href="#">Calculator</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-518" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-518"><a href="#">Download Papers/Book Free</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-519" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-519"><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

what you need to add to the .submenu is "text-align: right", I modified your code

```
.sub-menu{display:none;position:absolute;width:150px;box-shadow:0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); text-align: right;}
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. Your sub-menu items are still anchored to the left-side of their parent `li` elements and cause a horizontal overflow on the page.